# I need to write a while loop that will iterate 10 times with a value of count from 1 to 10 in java

Tags: java, while-loop

This is what I have so far I have tried many things but none of them work and I'm out of ideas. I know the exercise is simple but I just can't get it to print 1 to 10 ten times. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num1 = 1;

    while(num1 <= 10){          
        System.out.println(num1);
num1++;
    }   
}
```

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
this is only what I'm getting when I run

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.** In this case, be sure to look for the part covering adding to variables, or "incrementing" variables. It would also be a good place for a `for` loop rather than `while`.

Comment: See [The while and do-while statements docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and [The for statement docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). You are not modifying `num1` within the loop.

Comment: Step through your existing code line by line. What do you think you need to do after you've printed the value?

Comment: You forgot to increment `num1` inside the loop body.

Comment: In your example, the code in the loop will run, over and over again, as long as a variable (num1) is less than 10. Because of that do not forget to increase the variable (num1) used in the condition, otherwise the loop will never end!!

Answer (score 0):

Just add one to the counter variable.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    int num1 = 1;

    while(num1 <= 10){          
        System.out.println(num1);   
        num1 += 1;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add num1++ after system.out.println();